# What does Heads cannot be resolved to a variable mean?

Tags: java, variables

Sorry to bother you. I have been trying to create a very simple java cointoss simulator recently. here is the code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CoinToss {
static String choice;
static String answer;
static Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print("Heads or Tails?");
    choice = user_input.nextLine();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int side = rand.nextInt(2);
    if (side == 0){
        answer = Heads;
        System.out.println("Heads");
        if (answer == choice) {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        }
    }
    else if (side == 1){
        answer = Tails;
        System.out.println("Tails");
        if (answer == choice) {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        }

    }
}
}
```

When I try to build and run I get an error message saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Heads cannot be resolved to a variable
Tails cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: You said `answer` is of type String, so the value you're assigning should be enclosed in double quotes like `answer = "Heads"`

Comment: Also, compare strings using `equals()`, not `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are referring to a non existing variable :

```
answer = Heads;
```

You probably meant :

```
answer = "Heads";
```

BTW, you should also change `answer == choice` to `answer.equals(choice)` if you want your String comparison to work.

Comment: @emtekcan Did you read what I wrote regarding using `answer.equals(choice)`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to reply to another comment with that :P. I just read it and tried. It works like I want it to. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The way you wrote `answer = Heads;` means assign the variable `Heads` to the variable `answer`.

Instead you probably want `answer = "Heads";`, and `answer = "Tails";`.

Answer (score 0):

It's this line:

```
answer = Heads;
```

You're assigning the value of `Heads` to the variable `answer`. Because there are no parentheses after `Heads` (ie, it's not `Heads()`), it must refer to a variable: either a local variable, a static variable or an instance variable.

But nowhere do you declare such a variable, so the compiler can't figure out what you mean (ie, it can't resolve the variable name to a variable).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. The only problem is that if i do add parantheses, I get a result like this: Heads or Tails?Heads
Heads
You lose!          Even though I wrote heads, and the randomizer chose heads, i lost

Answer (score 0):

Heads and Tails are not defined. Since "Answer" is a string you can use "Heads" and "Tails" when you assign the result.